# Blue Screen Issue in windows 7

Tags: crash, bsod

I am having trouble figuring out this blue screen issue. This is a dump from NirSofts blue screen view

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 090913-28516-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/9/2013 9:53:31 AM
Bug Check String  : KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001e
Parameter 1       : ffffffff`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffff800`0337e93a
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000001
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000018
Caused By Driver  : NETIO.SYS
Caused By Address : NETIO.SYS+ce7b
File Description  : Network I/O Subsystem
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.17939 (win7sp1_gdr.120822-0331)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\090913-28516-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,560
Dump File Time    : 9/9/2013 9:56:29 AM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 090813-38688-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/8/2013 5:00:50 PM
Bug Check String  : KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001e
Parameter 1       : ffffffff`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffffa80`0780f610
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 000007ff`fffa8000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18205 (win7sp1_gdr.130708-1532)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\090813-38688-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,560
Dump File Time    : 9/8/2013 5:35:54 PM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 090813-44741-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/8/2013 4:01:37 PM
Bug Check String  : KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001e
Parameter 1       : ffffffff`c0000096
Parameter 2       : fffff800`0310cdfa
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18205 (win7sp1_gdr.130708-1532)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\090813-44741-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,560
Dump File Time    : 9/8/2013 4:57:50 PM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 090813-45006-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/8/2013 3:19:58 PM
Bug Check String  : KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001e
Parameter 1       : ffffffff`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffffa80`077943ef
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`fffa003c
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18205 (win7sp1_gdr.130708-1532)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b80
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\windows\Minidump\090813-45006-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 274,560
Dump File Time    : 9/8/2013 3:56:50 PM
==================================================
```

My questions are: what is causing these bluescreens and how can i fix it?

I can boot into safe mode with networking, but a full boot the computer BSODS after a few minutes

Comment: upload all dmp files to skydrive/dropbox so that I can look at them with a real debugger.

Comment: okay, will do when I get home.

Comment: have you uploaded them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blue screens are actually done by Windows itself for it shuts down your system before damage can occur.

NETIO.sys is a Windows driver and it has to do with networking/internet. Update your wireless/NIC drivers. Does this help?

Comment: I'll look into it when I get home. I am able to boot with Safe mode with networking, but not full boot.